# Is there an analytical solution for the following optimization problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, least-squares, non-convex-optimization, qcqp

We need to solve the following least square problem
$$\min_x (Y-Ax)^T(Y-Ax)$$
$$s.t. x^TA^TAx=1$$
in a closed form, where $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ are given.

Can anyone help us? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is $A$ full rank? If yes, then letting $z=Ax$ simplifies a lot.

Comment: Why are some vectors uppercase and others lowercase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is if $A$ is full rank. To see that, you can build the Lagrangian

$$(y-Ax)^T(y-Ax)-\lambda(x^TA^TAx-1).$$

The derivative with respect to $x$ is given by

$$2x^TA^TA-2y^TA-2\lambda x^TA^TA.$$

Equating this to zero yields the solution

$$x^{*T}=y^TA(A^TA)^{-1}/(1-\lambda).$$

The Hessian is given by $2A^TA(1-\lambda)$ and must be positive to ensure that we have a minimum. We will get back to that later.

From the constraint $x^TA^TAx-1=0$, we get that

$$(1-\lambda)^2=y^TA(A^TA)^{-1}A^Ty.$$

Solutions to that equation are

$$\lambda=1\pm\sqrt{\alpha},\ \alpha:=y^TA(A^TA)^{-1}A^Ty.$$

The minimum is attained for

This yields $\lambda=1-\sqrt{\alpha}$ since this value makes the Hessian positive definite, which yields

$$x^*=\dfrac{(A^TA)^{-1}A^Ty}{(y^TA(A^TA)^{-1}A^Ty)^{1/2}}$$

Comment: We have $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Therefore, if $A$ is full rank, it is invertible. This means $(A^TA)^{-1} = A^{-1}(A^T)^{-1}$ and $x^{\star} =\frac{A^{-1}y}{\sqrt{y^Ty}}$.

Comment: @ReinhardMeier Yes, this is true. I kept this form because it remains valid when $A$ is rectangular with full column rank.

Comment: Thanks a lot! : )This is very helpful for us

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\a{\alpha}  \def\b{\beta}  \def\g{\gamma} \def\t{\theta}
\def\l{\lambda} \def\s{\sigma} \def\e{\varepsilon}
\def\ll{\l^{-1}} \def\ss{\s^{-1}}
\def\lll{\l^{-2}} \def\sss{\s^{-2}}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vecc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\op{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$Write the problem as
$$\eqalign{
\min_x\:&\tfrac12\frob{Ax-y}^2 \\
\op{s.t.}\:&\frob{Ax}^2 = \o \\
}$$
It will be convenient to use a colon to denote
the matrix inner product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \frob{A}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \} \\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \\
C:\LR{AB} &= \LR{CB^T}:A = \LR{A^TC}:B \\
}$$
when applied to vectors $\,(n=\o)\,$ this reduces to
a standard dot product.

First, introduce an **unconstrained** vector $u$ and use it to construct
the $x$ vector
$$\eqalign{
\l^2 &= \frob{Au}^2 = u^TA^TAu &\qiq \l\:d\l = u^TA^TA\:du \\
\c{x} &\c{=} \c{\ll u} &\qiq \frob{Ax}^2 = \lll\frob{Au}^2 = \o \\
dx &= \ll\:du-u\lll\:d\l \\
  &= \ll\LR{I-xx^TA^TA}&du \\
}$$
Then calculate the gradient of the cost function with respect to $u$
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \tfrac12(Ax-y):(Ax-y) \\
d\phi &= \LR{A^TAx-A^Ty}:dx \\
 &= \ll\LR{I-A^TAxx^T}\LR{A^TAx-A^Ty}:du \\
\grad{\phi}{u}
 &= \ll\LR{I-A^TAxx^T}\LR{A^TAx-A^Ty} \\
}$$
The $\sf zero$-$\sf gradient$ condition becomes
$$\eqalign{
&\c{A^TAx} - A^Ty = \c{A^TAx}\LR{x^TA^TAx} - \c{A^TAx}\LR{x^TA^Ty} \\
&\LR{y^TAx}\c{A^TAx} = A^Ty \\
&\s A^TAx = A^Ty \\
&x = \ss A^+y \\
}$$
So the constrained solution is simply a scalar multiple of the
unconstrained solution.

The constraint condition can be used to determine
the scale factor
$$\eqalign{
\o &= Ax:Ax \\
 &= \LR{\ss AA^+y}:\LR{\ss AA^+y}  \\
 &= \sss y^T\c{AA^+AA^+}y \\
\s^2 &= y^T\c{AA^+}y \\
}$$
Therefore the closed-form solution of the problem is
$$\eqalign{
x = \frac{A^+y}{\sqrt{y^TAA^+y}} \\
}$$
where $A^+$ denotes the pseudoinverse of $A$.